# Spring rabbit does not allow overriding defaults in caching connection factory configuration : release 1.1.4

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I trying a spring amqp application to send JSON data as messages to a consumer (written in Ruby).

I get connection reset errors with any setting that I try

**NOTE:** I deleted the default guest user and added admin with the same privileges over default virtual host.

Here's the configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="channelCacheSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="admin" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="admin" />
</beans:bean>

<rabbit:queue id='analytics.persistence.queue' name='analytics.persistence.queue' />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="amq.direct">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="analytics.persistence.queue">
        </rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="cachingConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory" />

<beans:bean id="rabbitTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="exchange" value="amq.direct" />
    <beans:property name="routingKey" value="analytics.persistence.queue"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="analyticsMessageProducer"
    class="hoodibaba.analytics.publish.AnalyticsPersistenceMessageProducer">
    <beans:property name="rabbitTemplate" ref="rabbitTemplate" />
</beans:bean>
```

And in my producer class

```
public class AnalyticsPersistenceMessageProducer extends RabbitGatewaySupport implements
    AnalyticsPersistenceMessageGateway {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnalyticsPersistenceMessageProducer.class);

  @Override
  public void sendAnalyticsMessage(String jsonData) {
    try {
      getRabbitTemplate().convertAndSend("analytics.persistence.queue",jsonData);
    } catch (AmqpException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
      logger.error("Exception Stacktrace",e);
      logger.error("flushing JSON data to logs: " + jsonData);
    }
  }

}
```

I get a

> com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly
>   caused by authentication failure exception

the stack trace shows connection reset

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:348)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:160)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:202)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:340)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:131)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:508)
```

The message consumer is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'bunny'

conn = Bunny.new("amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672")
conn.start

ch = conn.create_channel
puts 'channel created'
q = ch.queue("analytics.persistence.queue",:exclusive => false, :auto_delete => false)
x = ch.direct("amq.direct")
q.bind(x)
q.subscribe(:block => true, :ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  puts "Received #{payload}, message properties are #{properties.inspect}"
end
ch.close
con.close
```

**Update:** it seems the updated username and password settings are not propagated, rabbit logs show my application still uses guest

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Mar-2013::00:16:12 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.13815.0> (127.0.0.1:44736 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

(The OP edited the answer in the post. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The problem is in my configuration; caching connection factory is defined using both the beans namespace and rabbit namespcace, latter using the defaults. Changed to configuration to following and I do not get connection reset errors anymore

```
<rabbit:queue id='analytics.persistence.queue' name='analytics.persistence.queue' />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="amq.direct">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="analytics.persistence.queue">
        </rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    username="analytics" password="analytics" channel-cache-size="5"
    virtual-host="analytics" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory" />

<beans:bean id="rabbitTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="exchange" value="amq.direct" />
    <beans:property name="queue" value="analytics.persistence.queue" />
    <beans:property name="routingKey" value="save.analytics"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="analyticsMessageProducer"
    class="hoodibaba.analytics.publish.AnalyticsPersistenceMessageProducer"
    autowire="byName" />
```